# How to close mail in Gmail while using "Preview Pane" split mode?

Tags: gmail

[image]

I have started using split screen using "Preview Pane" in Gmail which is a new feature in Gmail (according to me).

How to close opened mail ?

Suppose I have clicked on a mail, that mail will be opened below mail list. I am not able to close that mail.

I want the screen as follows. Currently I am refreshing entire page to get such result.

[image]

Comment: The mode is called `Preview Pane` for anyone who wants to have a look at it. Also I couldnt find a way de-select a message other than refreshing the page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to enable keyboard shortcuts.

If you have the feature enabled, after you previewed an email, to "close" the preview, click <kbd>u</kbd>.

Comment: Isn't there any switch to close it ?

Comment: None that I know of (or see).

Comment: OK then ! Accepted !

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: 10 years later and this is still useful - gets the "refresh" button back after you preview a mail, which I need to tell gmail to fetch from a POP server, nice!